# How to set elevation color?

Tags: android, react-native

We have the proptype `elevation`in react-native ([doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style)), but how can I set the color of the "android-shadow" it's producing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the color of the shadow produced by Android's `setElevation` cannot be changed. Also, their Material Design guidelines around the web like [here](https://material.google.com/material-design/elevation-shadows.html) don't seem to indicate that you can change the color.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

In addition, box shadows in React Native are also not supported on Android, based on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2768#issuecomment-140794713).

Comment: if anyone is reading this, its a very old question, you can now do it I actually just did

Answer (score 6):

You can change shadow colors on Views starting API 28 (Pie) with [View#setOutlineAmbientShadowColor(int color)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOutlineAmbientShadowColor(int)) and [View#setOutlineSpotShadowColor(int color)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOutlineSpotShadowColor(int)) if you use elevation.

Comment: You're right but how do I get this working on a React Native app? For sure I need to change or invoke it but where?

Comment: @FrederikoCesar, did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @MayankMehtani No, with elevation color is not possible for me. But I managed to "fake" this behaviour haha.

You can change the color of the border, and then create more than one border at the component (using layers of views) by using colors that is similar to a fading effect.

Comment: @FrederikoCesar - hahaha.. good one.. can you plz share that shadow component .. like you did it?

Answer (score 1):

As per @rclai Answer, You cannot change the Elevation color in Android.

Instead of using Elevation you can try this React Native Shadow library which uses svg to produce shadow that let you set color, offset, opacity:
https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to change the elevation color in android