# Is there any way to change the color of elevation of a view android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the color of elevation(shadow) of view. Actually, I want to set a shadow on view with custom color. the shadow is blurred like elevation shadow.

Comment: I am having same issue , Please paste your solution when you solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the color of elevation shadow provided by the framework but you can use library to do so, please refer 
[this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187313/android-change-material-elevation-shadow-color)

Comment: This answer is copy pasted from the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Shadows) and does not answer the quastion in any way.