# How to change color of the line that top of the bottom navigation view

Tags: android, background-color, bottomnavigationview

I want to set backgroundColor as white for bottom navigation view. But there is a top shadow.

[image]

I want to change this color. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the colour of elevation shadow provided by the framework but you can use the library to do so, please refer [Lib](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon)

[Check this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187313/android-change-material-elevation-shadow-color)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `app:elevation="0dp"` . It should remove the shadow

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" 
    app:elevation="0dp"/>
```

Then  take a 9 patch image with your color shadow and set it as background

Comment: I don't want to remove the shadow. I want to change its color.

Comment: Take a 9 patch image with your color shadow and set it as background

Answer (score 0):

Use the code
Create shadow.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#757575"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="90"/>


</shape>
```

Call this in layout xml

```
 <View
            android:background="@drawable/dgb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_8sdp"/>
```