# Neumorphic cards on Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement neumorphic cards on Android using `elevation` attribute and new `outlineSpotShadowColor` attribute.

This is what I got so far:

[image]

XML code:

```
android:elevation="35dp"
android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#9677d8"
```

Background shape:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#b18cfe" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

As you can see the second card has different shadow colour on different sides.

How to do this on Android?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765631/295004

Comment: Could you provide more code of your view. It is quite an achievement!

Comment: @MorrisonChang I used outlineSpotShadowColor and it helps a bit, but I still can't have different shadow colour for different sides using just those attributes...

Comment: @felislynx.silae this is basically all the code. It's just a View with `elevation` and `outlineSpotShadowColor`. I also made rounded corners using shape background

Comment: @felislynx.silae I've updated my answer with background shape code.

Answer (score 0):

**For Best effect of neumorphism use this github Library:** [fornewid/neumorphism](https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism)

For more Reference you can visit medium link: [Medium Blog](https://fornewid.medium.com/neumorphism-in-android-9cf15e2122dc)