# How do you add a shadow on a button with your own colour?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, button, layout

How do you add a shadow on a button with your own colour? The button is set on a gradient background and I have various buttons that require shadows (preferably different colours). Can this be done or if not, how would I create a standard shadow?

[image][image]

Comment: There are some tricks but depends on what kind of shadow you need. Add a screenshot or an image that shows the shadow, so people can help you.

Comment: @aytek I've just added a couple of screenshots

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187313/android-change-material-elevation-shadow-color

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button