# How to change shadow elevation color on Android?

Tags: android, android-view, material-components-android

Is some way to change the material elevation shadow color? I already read [shadow clipping](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping) from Android documentation and it is actually not showing any code sample that is usefull for this requirement. I also saw the [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon) library, but Im trying to avoid third party solutions for something that SHOULD actually be easy to do. The only approach I found till now is the following:

```
    <style name="Widget.AppName.View.White">
        <item name="android:elevation">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_round_corners_white</item>
        <item name="android:outlineSpotShadowColor">@color/colorViewShadow</item>
        <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

But it only works on Android API 28 and above, and the current app Im working on has API 21 as minSdk.

Comment: It's already answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187313/android-change-material-elevation-shadow-color

Comment: The question mention "avoid third party solutions" and the link you provide highlight the Carbon Library as the answer, that is not the purpose of the question.

Comment: hey guy, please scroll to bottom and read all answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android change Material elevation shadow color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187313/android-change-material-elevation-shadow-color)

Comment: The question mention "avoid third party solutions" and the link you provide highlight the Carbon Library as the answer, that is not the purpose of the question.