# How to create Colored shadows for any view in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, shadow

I want to create shadow effect like [image: this] in ***android*** is there any library for it or any other trick to achieve this. or any method to change elevation color

Comment: Are you only looking for card view?

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29187313/android-change-material-elevation-shadow-color

Comment: No for any view